How do I separate SQL from code while using parametrised queries?
I'm using Microsoft.Data.Sqlite to query an SQLite database:
var myresult = dbContext.MyTable.FromSqlInterpolated($"select * from mytable where numericValue >= {dynamicNumericValueHere} limit 10;").ToList();

Which generates:
select *
from mytable
where numericValue >= @p0
limit 10;

This works, however I use an inline SQL string and this is a simplified version. The actual SQL has multiple lines with multiple parameters. There may also be different versions of the query. How do I move SQL out of the C# code while using parametrised queries? I want SQL in a separate file.

If the query is so big, why not create a view or function instead and map your objects to the view? EF is an ORM, not a database driver. Its job is to give the impression of working with objects instead of writing raw SQL or dealing with JOINs. SQL lines organised separately in a different file? make it a view

You should use FromSqlRaw to name parameters and populate them during execution.
Move the SQL to a separate file:
var sql = @"
    select
        *
    from mytable
    where numericValue >= @numericValue
    limit 10;
";

Execute the SQL in a different location:
var pNumericValue = new SqliteParameter("@numericValue", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int);
pNumericValue.Value = 10; // some value

var myresult = dbContext.MyTable
    .FromSqlRaw(sql, pNumericValue)
    .ToList();


Thanks, this worked. The thing that had thrown me off, incorrectly, was how I interpreted this article https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/raw-sql/from-sql. Towards teh end it says "Entity Framework Core will only parameterize format strings if they are supplied inline with the FromSqlRaw method call. Format strings declared outside of the FromSqlRaw method call will not be parsed for parameter placeholders." I assumed that it was true for interpolation too but I just checked your query and it's parameterising the numericvalue as expected.

I can suggest the following option.
Keep sql query strings in another file as regular strings with the format.
And before using, convert them to FormattableString.
// In another file
var rawSql = "select * from mytable where numericValue >= {0} limit 10;"

int value = 1;
var sql = FormattableStringFactory.Create(rawSql, value);

var myresult = dbContext.MyTable.FromSqlInterpolated(sql).ToList();

